# Android - Disable proximity sensor in my app

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that allows the user to start a phone call from the app itself and once the call was initiated, the user can get back to the app to do some UI actions.

My current problem is that once the call started the proximity sensor was enabled which makes it almost impossible to work with the app (depends on the sensitivity of the sensor - per device).

Is there anyway to control the sensor?
For example, I would like to disable the sensor once my activity is visible and re-enable it once invisible.

Thanks,
Lior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `WakeLock` in your application code...like below....

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "FullWakeLock" );
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: i can't confirm it works (even with "acquire") . did it work for you?

Comment: just to clarify : it disables the feature of turning off of the screen during calls even when you are very near the device (and by that , triggering the proximity sensor) ?

Comment: Maybe i didn't use it well then. can you please post the relevant code ?